# How to play m4v online in iPhone

Tags: ios4

Following is the URL. I want to play following URL video in my iPhone application. Please help me out to play this
http://www.example.com/SomeVideoOrAnother.m4v

I am building an application where I'll provide user list of movie or advertisement. User will select one of them and redirected to enjoy creative ad.

Comment: "Did not RTFM" alert! StackOverflow is being abused by people too lazy to read any documentation. Even too lazy to give any context.

Comment: Thanks Philippe, this may be my bad...But I am not aware of RTFM. can you guide me please from where I can read and get the information. I am new in iPhone development.

Comment: @KPT - RTFM is a way of telling you to "read the _______ manual" before you ask here. It's not an iOS term.

Comment: @Moshe: Your underscore is in the wrong place :-)

Comment: Oh.....my bad...Not familiar with the term :(. But is there anything that can help me out to play the video. I believe I have described my problem, but if you can help me out of this problem I'll be more than happy even with these abusive comments.

Comment: @KPT: open any single book on iPhone development, and you will find at least one chapter on playing video. Don't treat us as walking tutorials and reference manuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to not have done any background learning on iOS, judging by the broadness of your question.

I would recommend the [Apple Documentation (Getting started)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Getting+Started) as a good place to start.

Also, see some of [these books on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=ios+development&x=0&y=0).

To answer you question, there are a few frameworks to look into, for [example AV Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008072).